# Starting owlCarousel in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, carousel, owl-carousel

I am new to rails and this is the first time I want to use a carousel in a web application. My carousel appears, but it does not auto-play.
This is what I have in my application.js :

```
//= require owl.carousel
$(function(){ $(document).foundation(); });
var owl = $('.owl-carousel');
owl.owlCarousel({
    items:5,
    loop:true,
    margin:10,
    autoplay:true,
    autoplayTimeout:1000,
    autoplayHoverPause:true
});
```

And this is from my view:

```
<div id="owl" class="owl-carousel">
   <%  @artists.each do |artist| %>
       <div class="artist-card ">
          <%= link_to artist, class: "poster" do %>
            <%= image_tag artist.image.url(:thumb) %>
          <% end %>
          <div class="artist-info ell glassy-bg padmy padlx">
            <div class="artist-card ">
              <h6><%= artist.name %> <span>(<%= artist.instrument %>)</span></h6>
            </div>            
          </div>
        </div>
    <% end %>
</div>
```

Is there also a way to display every artist from my database in the carousel? I've seen that the default number of items for the carousel is 5. Can I make it dynamic ?

Comment: Any errors in the browser console ?

Comment: No, I didn't encounter any error.

Comment: Are you sure your DOM is fully loaded ? Try with $(document).ready(){} instead of foundation

Comment: Still not working. It behaves like a simple image slider, it does not play.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to solve the issue. Here is what I've done:

```
(function ($) {
  $(document).ready(function() {
    if ($('.carousel .owl-wrapper-outer').length === 0) {
      var owl = $('.carousel').owlCarousel({
        items:5,
        loop:true,
        margin:10,
        autoPlay:1000,
        autoplayHoverPause:true,
        responsive: true,
        responsiveRefreshRate : 200,
        responsiveBaseWidth: window,
        });
      $('.carousel').hover(function() {
      owl.trigger('owl.stop');
    }, function(){
        owl.trigger('owl.play', 1000);
    });
}
```